# How to force bonus act change in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have some legendary material more than another and I would like to do bonus act for the material I need. Is there any way to change which act is bonus one at the moment?

I did try leaving game and starting again.
I did try exiting game and starting whole Diablo 3 again.
That did not help. Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: Join a public game. Not posting as answer as this fixes the core problem but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well in a way it is an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The game cycles through the default bonus act (the act that has the bonus when you first make a game), once per hour.

If you want the act to change to a different one, the only way is to complete the current bonus act.

Typically, most people will complete all 5 acts (with bonuses moving between acts) at once to keep their materials fairly even.  If you only need materials in particular acts, its a good idea to determine when that act becomes the default for the hour and then farm it repeatedly.

Also, as ardaozkal said in the comments, you can also join public bounty games and try to find a game with a different bonus act that's underway.

Comment: How can you farm one bonus act repeatedly? Won't it automatically change on completion of current act?

Comment: @Eugene it will change, but as long as you are still within the hour you can leave the game and make a new one